# For $M'\to M$, what are the induced maps $F\otimes M' \to F\otimes M$?

Tags: modules, tensor-products, flatness

I have just read the definition of a flat module, and it is an $R$-module $F$ such that every monomorphism $M'\to M$ of $R$-modules induces a monomorphism:
$$F\otimes M'\to F\otimes M,$$
but I wonder what induces means here.

I know that I have maps from $F,M'$ to $F\times M'$ and maps from $F,M$ to $F\times M$ as well as maps from $F\times M'\to F\otimes M'$ and $F\times M\to F\otimes M$, so I imagine my $M'\to M$ should induce our map via:
$$\begin{array}{ccc}F\otimes M' &\stackrel{\psi^{\#}}\to&F\otimes M\\\uparrow&&\uparrow\\F\times M'&\stackrel{\psi}\to&F\times M\\\uparrow &&\uparrow\\M'&\longrightarrow&M \end{array}$$

Is that correct? So $\psi(f,m')=(a,m), \psi^\#(f\otimes m')=a\otimes m$, and we ask that the two squares commute?

Comment: @RenanManeliMezabarba Surely that would make every module flat?

Comment: @RenanManeliMezabarba Actually you are probably right. It'll fail to be flat when I move coefficients over the tensor. Although $p:\Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z$ is injective, the map $\text{Id}\otimes p:\Bbb Z_p\otimes \Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z_p\otimes \Bbb Z$ is not injective

Comment: Thanks @RenanManeliMezabarba!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The “induced morphism” by $f\colon M'\to M$ is the unique morphism $1\otimes f\colon F\otimes M'\to F\otimes M$ such that, for all $x\in F$ and $y\in M'$,
$$
(1\otimes f)(x\otimes y)=x\otimes f(y)
$$
By the properties of tensor products this is well defined.

It's essentially the upper square in your diagram. The lower square is not well defined, though: what should the map $M\to F\times M$ be?